# Can't watch videos on any browser

Tags: video, browser, flash

I'm trying to watch videos on YouTube in my browser but I can't. I installed the latest versions of Adobe Flash (11.5.500.80 Beta & 11.4.402.278) but it did not help.

I tried on Chrome 22, Firefox 13 and IE 8 and nothing works. My OS is Windows 7 32 bit.

What should I do? Should I install other Silverlight or Shockwave?

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Latest version of flash for IE is 11.4.402.278....http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: can you also tell us what the error you see says?

Comment: @moab I installed version 11.4.402.278 . but no success. can I watch the videos in ssl ?

Comment: Yes, I just watched the video you posted in the screenshot using HTTPS

Answer (score -1):

You installed a beta version of flash? No no no. Remove and install a 32 bit stable version from Adobe.

Comment: I had the same error on a stable version. I think that was 11.3.31.331

Comment: can you watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ixsn81SqU6E&feature=g-logo-xit with ssl ?

Comment: Under accessories crack open IE with no addons just to make sure its not some buggy plugin or toolbar. You may also try clearing cookies and other cached browser data. Also ensure that you have the latest updates for Windows, Flash and your browser of choice. Doing a clean boot of Windows wouldn't be a bad idea either.

Answer (score -1):

Close all browsers, [uninstall Flash completely](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html#main_Download_the_Adobe_Flash_Player_uninstaller), reboot, then reinstall and try again.